# Rails Mysql ORDER BY created_at with two rows created at the same time returning unexpected results

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm changing my Rails 3.2 app from Postgres to Mysql,

I have a model with default_scope :order => 'posts.created_at DESC'

if i query for posts with IDs between with the following code:

```
Post.find(:all, :conditions => ['id >= ? AND id <= ?', min_id.to_i, max_id.to_i]) if min_id && max_id
```

I get wrong ordered results (because multiple rows have the same created_at time),
for example: if post1 was created by code before post2 but they have the same created_at timestamp I would expect the query to return [post2, post1] because post2 was created "later". but I get the opposite result.

with Postgres I didn't have this issue.

why is it different ? how do I solve it ?

Comment: If they are equal in the ordering, why would you have any expectation of one result over the other?  Indeed, if they are truly equal, why does it matter?  If it does matter, you should specify the criteria by which you differentiate them/expect the ordering as a second clause to `ORDER BY`:  e.g. `ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC, posts.id DESC`.

Comment: I changed the model's default_scope to posts.created_at DESC, posts.id DESC and everything is ok now.so Postgres is ordering by the primary key by default ?

Comment: Seems like postgres has more accurate DATETIMEs than mysql (microseconds vs seconds): http://www.ispirer.com/wiki/sqlways/mysql/data-types/datetime
You probably lost the nanoseconds after you migrated your data to mysql so the DATETIME is the same, when it wasn't in postgres.